# Jira plugin in Jenkins not working but No error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, devops

I have set up my Jira plugin within Jenkins with working credentials.
When I run the following script:

```
jiraComment body: 'Comment test', issueKey: 'CAT-98'
```

The build is successful but the Jira ticket does not get a new comment

Edit: There was some problem with the credentials. Also in the Jenkins build, the right URL needed to be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution, but I would start by checking Jenkins logs (`http://jenkins-srv:8080/log/all`) to see if there's more info when the Jira plugin runs.
Or, even create a new Log Recorder to narrow the logs down to only Jira plugin related logs.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue, and basically I had to go to **Manage Jenkins** -> **System** -> **Jira Sights**
Then set URL and the Credentials

The credentials are basically the email of the user plus a token you can generate inside of Jira.
To read more about it you can go to
https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira/

[Jenkins Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BeOR.png)